# WooCommerce shows random product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I have set products with some product attributes, but I didn't add one specific attribute.

This:

```
$product->get_attribute( 'pa_material' );
```

works fine. If product has attributes "material" it shows them if they are set, if not i get empty value, but when i'm using this:

```
get_the_terms($id, 'pa_material');
```

And there is no attribute "material" in product, I get random attributes like "wood", "steel, "glass".

I've checked database and there is no "material" attribute.

It's not big problem in my function, but it seems to be problem for WooCommerce in filters on archive pages. When i check "wood" in materials, i get products without set attributes "material".

I think it can be related to the problem with **`get_the_terms()`** function.

Comment: In Woocommerce, **if you don't add at least one term to a given product attribute, you can NOT set it in a product**. So there is something wrong in your question **because it's not possible to have an empty product attribute set for a product** and in this case, get_the_terms() returns nothing… I have test that.

Comment: I know about it. I didn't add this attribute to product and still get_the_terms returns random attributes but get_attribute returns empty value.